# Saving many to many relationship in EF 6.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have read many topics on saving a many to many relationship with EF 6.1, but I'm not getting any further. The join table with `reservationId` and `facilityId` is still empty after I save my reservation.

These are my models:

```
public class Reservation
{ 
    [Key]
    public int reservationId { get; set; }

    //Lijst met Facilities, Many to Many
    public virtual ICollection<Facility> FacilitiesList { get; set; }
}

public class Facility
{
    [Key]
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }
    public decimal FacilityPrice { get; set; }
    public string FacilityType { get; set; }

    //Many to Many
    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> reservationList { get; set; }

    public Facility()
    {
        //Instantiate our implementation of ICollection
        this.reservationList = new HashSet<Reservation>();
    }
}
```

I create the join table by overriding OnModelCreating:

```
public partial class DataContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>()
                    .HasMany<Facility>(s => s.FacilitiesList)
                    .WithMany(c => c.reservationList)
                    .Map(cs =>
                    {
                        cs.MapLeftKey("ReservationId");
                        cs.MapRightKey("FacilityId");
                        cs.ToTable("ReservationFacility");
                    });

    }
}
```

Edit: Here is where I save a reservation:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.FacilitiesList = new SelectList(_facilityrepository.GetAll(), "FacilityId", "FacilityType");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ReservationId,ArrivalDate,LeaveDate,CampingSpotId,UserId,PersonsAmount,FacilityType,FacilityPrice")] Reservation reservation) 
    {
        _reservationrepository.Add(reservation);
        return RedirectToAction("ShowAvailableSpots", new { ArrivalDate = reservation.ArrivalDate, LeaveDate = reservation.LeaveDate, ReservationID = reservation.ReservationId });
    }
```

Now I have the tables. I can save facilities and I can select them when creating a reservation with a MultiSelectList.

Why is the join table always empty? What do I have to do to fill the `FacilitiesList` so I can get this data anywhere in my project?

Comment: Can you add the code where you save a `Reservation`?

Comment: you exclude the only part of your code that we need to see! :)

Comment: ok thx for code. I can see youre adding `_reservationrepository.Add(reservation);` but not where its saved to context with relevant `FacilitiesList `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was completely new to this I didn't had a clue that I needed to initialise and populate the list. Thx to @dellywheel for pointing me in the right direction!

Here's the working code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ReservationId,ArrivalDate,LeaveDate,CampingSpotId,UserId,PersonsAmount,FacilityType,FacilityPrice")] Reservation reservation, int[] SelectedFacilities) 
    {
        //Instantiate our facilities list!
        reservation.FacilitiesList = new List<Facility>();

        foreach (int facId in SelectedFacilities)
        {
            var facType = _facilityrepository.GetFacilityType(facId);
            var facPrice = _facilityrepository.GetFacilityPricePerDay(facId);
            reservation.FacilitiesList.Add(new Facility { FacilityId = facId, FacilityType = facType, FacilityPrice = facPrice} );
        }

        _reservationrepository.Add(reservation);
        return View() //code omitted 
    }
```